# Is it possible to recover my open tabs on safari ios after clearing history and website data from settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, safari, tabs

I stupidly tapped the 'Clear History and Website Data' option from Safari's settings on iOS, without realizing it would close my open tabs. Now I want them back. I check my other devices to see if I could see the sync'ed iCloud tabs but they were not there (side note: this feature seems very buggy). Are there any other hacks to retrieve my closed tabs?

Comment: If you tap and hold the '+' button in Safari, do you see a list of previous tabs?

Comment: No I do not see any previous tabs there

Comment: I think you're out of luck.  If you didn't clear the history and data you might've had a chance.

Comment: I figured as much, but was hoping I was wrong 